# Not storing variable from powershell .Net code

Tags: powershell, .net

I have the following code, but its not saving the selection into a variable. I'm not the best at these so could do with some help please.

It's supposed to save the selection into the $x variable, which then spits out the selection on the last line.

```
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms")
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Drawing") 

$objForm = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form 
$objForm.Text = "Select a Computer"
$objForm.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(300,200) 
$objForm.StartPosition = "CenterScreen"

$objForm.KeyPreview = $True
$objForm.Add_KeyDown({if ($_.KeyCode -eq "Enter") 
    {$x=$objListBox.SelectedItem;$objForm.Close()}})
$objForm.Add_KeyDown({if ($_.KeyCode -eq "Escape") 
    {$objForm.Close()}})

$OKButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$OKButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,120)
$OKButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,23)
$OKButton.Text = "OK"
$OKButton.Add_Click({$x=$objListBox.SelectedItem;$objForm.Close()})
$objForm.Controls.Add($OKButton)

$CancelButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$CancelButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(150,120)
$CancelButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,23)
$CancelButton.Text = "Cancel"
$CancelButton.Add_Click({$objForm.Close()})
$objForm.Controls.Add($CancelButton)

$objLabel = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$objLabel.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,20) 
$objLabel.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(280,20) 
$objLabel.Text = "Please select a computer:"
$objForm.Controls.Add($objLabel) 

$objListBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ListBox 
$objListBox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,40) 
$objListBox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(260,20) 
$objListBox.Height = 80

[void] $objListBox.Items.Add("atl-dc-001")
[void] $objListBox.Items.Add("atl-dc-002")
[void] $objListBox.Items.Add("atl-dc-003")
[void] $objListBox.Items.Add("atl-dc-004")
[void] $objListBox.Items.Add("atl-dc-005")
[void] $objListBox.Items.Add("atl-dc-006")
[void] $objListBox.Items.Add("atl-dc-007")

$objForm.Controls.Add($objListBox) 

$objForm.Topmost = $True

$objForm.Add_Shown({$objForm.Activate()})
[void] $objForm.ShowDialog()

$x
```

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its stored in the `$objListBox` variable. You can call it by selecting the `SelectedItem` property. So if you want the `$x` variable to return the selected value, fill it with  `$objListBox.SelectedItem`:

```
    $x = $objListBox.SelectedItem
    $x
    atl-dc-002
```

You can check the various properties, methods events of powershell objects by using the `Get-Member` cmd-let.